# How to better block phishing spam due to heartbleed?

Tags: spam, spam-filter, heartbleed

I imagine it won't take long for spammers to recognize that Heartbleed is an ideal way to do phishing. I am thinking of ways to mitigate the phishing risk, I mean just this time for the heartbleed bug, not generally.

End-users will likely receive many official emails asking to go to a website and reset the password. Maybe this even becomes advertised in radio or television. If spammers do a good job, they can easily slip in and have a high success rate.

**What can I do as a server administrator (particularly hosting IMAP servers) to filter specifically the heartbleed spam and let official mails through?**

I already have general spam filters applied and grey-listing enabled. But if I had e.g. a more complete list than [the top 500](https://gist.github.com/dberkholz/10157113)  vulnerable sites, it would be possible to only forward mails sent by those domains and disallow others. Of course that list should be confirmed by some more official organization.

Comment: Send out an email to your users reminding them never to click links in an email like that, but instead to open a browser and go to the correct web site that they have used before instead?

Comment: @psusi Heartbleed makes a nasty kind of phish possible:  After locating a web site which still has the vulneratbility, the phisher send a "legitimate" email which links to the correct site.  This is done in order to increase traffic to the site.  The attacker then uses the heartbleed exploit to mine passwords and what-not.  The phish isn't the main attack, but it's a way to make the main attack more fruitful.

Comment: @WayneConrad, I would hope that sites would have shut down and patched already.

Comment: @psusi Even people who should know better don't always do the right thing. Or they may have business processes that prevent them from acting in a timely manner. For instance, a large company that sounds similar to Yeehaw! was leaking user data for many hours after patches were available. They might still be, for all I know.